# what does"power politics" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

Machiavelli was a product of Renaissance Florence, a city-state that was struggling for expansion and survival among a competing group of similar states. As a public servant and diplomat, Machiavelli came to understand **power politics** by observing the spectacle around him without any illusions.

Would you possibly elaborate what the bold part means? and is power an adjective there??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Power* in *power politics* is an attributive noun: a noun which modifies a following noun, like *internet* in *internet conversation*.

*Power politics* is politics understood as fundamentally a competition between rival states or classes or  interests, each seeking  to impose its own will on its competitors. It is contrasted with traditional views of politics as a rational system oriented toward achieving ethical goals.

Comment: @nima You're welcome. I should point out (to spare you future embarrassment) that in English it is safer to address only family, lovers and intimate friends as *dear*.